# How to display a point cloud inside MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, point-clouds

I am building a GUI in MATLAB and I want to display point clouds in a figure inside this GUI. The GUI plays a 3D recording and enables me to pause/play, change speeds and change the video I am playing.

So far I've used *pcplayer* to display point clouds. For example:

```
player = pcplayer(xlimits, ylimits, zlimits, 'MarkerSize', 100);
view(player,point_cloud);
```

However this opens up a new figure. I've tried using *pcshow*:

```
pcshow(point_cloud, 'Parent', axes_to_plot);
```

This worked, but only for the first frame of the video. Afterwards I receive an error:

> Property assignment is not allowed when the object is empty.  Use subscripted assignment to create an array element.

This is not a problem with the clouds that I am trying to draw: they are not empty, and in addition trying to draw the same cloud twice results in the same error. There is something happening there that I do not understand.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

I am using MATLAB version 2016a.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same problem with the exact same error. This started since I have started to use matlab 2016b, did not have this problem with 2015b. I don't have exact solution, but what I did is that I put the pcshow to try catch environment to suppress the error. It works for me because pcshow makes the figure and then throws the error.

```
 try
    pcshow(point_cloud, 'Parent', axes_to_plot);
 catch
 end
```

Again this is not the solution to resolve  the error, but could make your code work, it did mine.